# Is this thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Is this thread safe?

```
private static bool close_thread_running = false;
public static void StartBrowserCleaning()
{
    lock (close_thread_running)
    {
        if (close_thread_running)
            return;

        close_thread_running = true;
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (close_thread_running)
            {
                if (!close_thread_running)
                    break;
            }

            CleanBrowsers();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }));

    thread.Start();
}

public static void StopBrowserCleaning()
{
    lock (close_thread_running)
    {
        close_thread_running = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why am I thinking Marathon Man?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it won't even compile, because you're trying to lock on a value type.

Introduce a separate lock variable of a reference type, e.g.

```
private static readonly object padlock = new object();
```

Aside from that:

If `StopBrowserCleaning()` is called while there *is* a cleaning thread (while it's sleeping), but then `StartBrowserCleaning()` is called again before the first thread notices that it's meant to shut down, you'll end up with two threads.

You might want to consider having two variables - one for "is there meant to be a cleaning thread" and one for "is there actually a cleaning thread."

Also, if you use a monitor with `Wait/Pulse`, or an `EventHandle` (e.g. `ManualResetEvent`) you can make your sleep a more reactive waiting time, where a request to stop will be handled more quickly.

Comment: I'd say that something which doesn't compile is technically threadsafe - it'll never deadlock or encounter race conditions :-)

Comment: does that mean my car is air-safe since it can never fly and thus never encounter a mid-air collision?

Comment: I've never heard about 'air-safety' before, but of course. Why wouldn't it be? It is also space travel safe.

Comment: Changed first word from "no" to "well"... I think I'd say that the thread safety of code which doesn't compile is undefined. The code can't run safely on multiple threads, after all.